# Why is the set of all intervals on [0,1] not a sigma algebra

Tags: probability-theory

I am working my way through "A First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory" by Rosenthal and I'm a bit confused by something.

In chapter 2 p.9 he mentions the set $J$ as being all intervals (open/closed/half-open/singleton/empty) contained in $[0,1]$

He then goes on to say that $J$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

My question is why not? I have gathered by trawling this site that it fails the condition because it is not closed under countable unions - could someone please provide a sort of "proof" of that?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something here but $[0.1,0.2]\cup [0.3,0.4]\cup_{i=3}^{\infty}\emptyset=[0.1,0.2]\cup [0.3,0.4]$ is not an interval.

Comment: The union of two disjoint intervals in $J$, as an example take $[1/4,1/3]\cup[3/4,1]$, does not belong to $J$.

Comment: It doesn't even contain all the open sets, as it's not closed under finite unions, let alone countable unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $J$ generates a $\sigma$-algebra, but $J$ itself is not one, since for example, the complement of an open interval is not an interval.

Comment: So does it fail as a sigma-algebra because it is not closed under complements?

Comment: Yes, nor under unions.

Comment: Right - it's not closed under unions because (as someone above said), if you take the union of two disjoint sets, that is not an interval. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are intervals and $c>b$, then $(a,b)\cup (c,d)$ is not an interval.  In an interval $I$, if $x,y\in I$ then any $z$ with $x\le z \le y$ is also in $I$.  In contrast, in the union described, $(1/2)(a+b)$ and $(1/2)(c+d)$ belong to the union, while $b$ and $c$, which lie between $(1/2)(a+b)$ and $(1/2)(c+d)$, do not:  the union is therefore not an interval.