# The collection of countable unions of intervals is not a sigma-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I resume the question asked by SocraticParadox in [Proving the set of all finite or countable unions of intervals is not a Sigma Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628015/proving-the-set-of-all-finite-or-countable-unions-of-intervals-is-not-a-sigma-al).
I have tinked two proofs but I need confirmation. Here are two statements:

1) The collection of countable unions of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ is not a sigma-algebra.

2) There exists some Borel sets that are not countable unions of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$.

It seems that these two statements are equivalent:

Let $\mathcal{I}$  the collection of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{H}$  the collection of countable unions of intervals of $\mathbb{R}$  and $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ the Borel sigma-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$. We know that $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) = \sigma \left( \mathcal{I} \right)$.
Firstly $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{H}$. On the other hand, any interval is a Borel set, thus any countable union of intervals is a Borel set, thus $\mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$. Finally we have $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{H} \subset \mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$.

To prove that $1) \Leftrightarrow 2)$, we prove the reverse, i.e. $\mathcal{H}$ is a sigma-algebra $ \Leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) = \mathcal{H}$.

Since $\mathcal{I} \subset \mathcal{H}$, if $\mathcal{H}$ is a sigma-algebra, then by minimality, we have $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) = \sigma \left( \mathcal{I} \right) \subset \mathcal{H}$, then $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) = \mathcal{H}$.

Conversely, if $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right) = \mathcal{H}$, then $\mathcal{H}$ is a sigma-algebra since $\mathcal{B}\left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ is a sigma-algebra.

Is this right?

Second question. I have tried to prove 2):

Let $K$ the Cantor ternary set. $K$ is a Borel set. We assume that there exists a sequence $\left( {{I_n}} \right)$ of not empty intervals such that $K = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {{I_n}} $. If each ${I_n}$ is a singleton$\left[ {{x_n},{x_n}} \right] = \left\{ {{x_n}} \right\}$, then $K = \bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} {\left\{ {{x_n}} \right\}}  = \left\{ {{x_n},\;n \in \mathbb{N}} \right\}$, thus $K$ is a countable set. But $K$ is an uncountable set , thus there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that ${I_N}$ is not a singleton.
${I_N}$ contains two different points $x$ and $y$, then $\left] {x,y} \right[ \subset {I_N} \subset K$. This is impossible since the interior of $K$ is empty. $K$ is not a countable unions of intervals. 
Is this right? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, everything you write is correct :)

Comment: Thank you PhoemueX, I felt alone ! Jean Luc